# Flutter Map how to show city or an Area outline (With Flutter Map MapBox API , NO GOOGLE MAPS)

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

Does anyone know how to mark the area of a place knowing its latitude/longitude or with the name of the city, I have been looking for information but I have not found anything.

Thank you.

[image]